# Need full Taxonomy URL to be valid else redirect 404

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two taxonomy term pages with the following details:

1. Term id : 1 , url alias : fruits
2. Term id : 2 , url alias : fruits/apple

When I am typing url `http://www.example.com/fruits/apple` then content related to term id 2 is getting loaded which is correct

But the problem is when I am typing `http://www.example.com/fruits/apple1` which is not a valid url then the content of Term id 1 is getting loaded since it is matching till "fruits". In such scenario I want the site to be getting redirected to a 404 page instead of matching termid of "fruits".

I need the full taxonomy url to be valid or redirect to 404.

I am using views taxonomy term page (Default one which by default remains inactive) where a wild card character is there taxonomy/terms/%.

Please help. I cant find a suitable solution for the same.

Comment: Are you talking about 'admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit' view ??
Is it correct one 'taxonomy/terms/%' ??

Comment: Yes I am using the view. Can you please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using contextual filter, then there is validation criteria in settings of taxonomy term name you have selected. 
[image: When filter value is in URL]
Then add filter value type as taxonomy term name and add action as page not found. 
[image: Specify validation]

You will get the result.